# Nokia SDK for .NET developers

Tags: c#, sdk, nokia

is there any available SDK for nokia cellphones like texting while phone is connected via bluetooth.. receiving text messages to PC via phone connected to bluetooth.. just like Nokia PC Suite.. :) is it possible to develop something like that?

Comment: take a look at http://nokia-pc-connectivity-sdk.software.informer.com/

Comment: The program is unavailable for downloading: discontinued by the developer.

Comment: take a look at here http://nokia-pc-connectivity-sdk.software.informer.com/3.0/

Comment: anyway, i got some idea with your post.. :) i'm trying this http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/bd896b31-92ba-4624-aa9d-ebf732e7cc0d/Nokia_PC_Suite_Connectivity_API_1_1.html